# Laravel Query-Builder

Tags: laravel

I need help to convert below SQL Query to Laravel Query Builder Syntax

```
Select * from schools where child_id in (select parent_id from schools where email = 'somemail@mail.com')
```

Thanks in advance for the support

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent_ids = DB::table('schools')->where('email', 'someemail@mail.com')->pluck('parent_id');
$children = DB::table('schools')->whereIn('child_id', $parent_ids)->get();
return $children;
```

Comment: Response Apprecited.